# Powershell: Get-Unique on one property, while sorting on two

Tags: powershell

I am generating a list using the following two statement:

```
$Directmembers = $memberdata | where-object {($_.huntpilot_number -eq $e.'Hunt Pilot number') -and ($_.directoryuri -like '*@*.*')} | select-object huntpilot_number, directoryuri, @{n="Origin";e={"DirectMember"}}

$Pickupmembers = $pickupdata | where-object {($_.huntpilot_number -eq $e.'Hunt Pilot number') -and ($_.directoryuri -like '*@*.*')} | select-object huntpilot_number, directoryuri, @{n="Origin";e={"PickupMember"}}

$members += $Directmembers
$members += $Pickupmembers
```

The last part selecting only the two columns I am interested in, and adding a new property Origin. (and then combining them in $members)

Now, I want to get each unique `directoryuri` in this list; but if the Origin is DirectMember, I want that to stay and the rest to be removed.

`($members | Sort-Object directoryuri -Unique)`

This returns the unique entries, but doesn't take the `Origin` in account.

When I add the Origin parameter in the `Sort-Object`, they are returning 2 entries: because they are no longer unique to each other.

How would I give priority to the Origin DirectMember, while Select-Unique?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$members | 
    # Group by directoryuri
    Group-Object directoryuri | 
    ForEach-Object {
        # For each group check if an item exists with Origin = 'DirectMember' and output it
        if ($match = $_.group | Where-Object Origin -EQ 'DirectMember') {
            $match | Select-Object -First 1
        }
        # else output the other
        else {
            $_.group | Select-Object -First 1
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks; had to filter the $match and $_,group again, because they had duplicate entries, but then at least I could filter out the actual duplicates. This works.

Comment: Ah, sorry about that.  I've added `| Select-Object -First 1` to ensure that only 1 item is returned